# Rewriting JOIN query into subqueries, missing rows?

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have the following MySQL query that returns these rows:

```
SELECT p.ID AS id, p.post_title AS title, p.post_author AS uid, SUM(v.pageviews) AS pageviews, IFNULL(c.comment_count, 0) AS comment_count 
FROM `views` v 
LEFT JOIN `posts` p ON v.postid = p.ID 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT comment_post_ID, COUNT(comment_post_ID) AS comment_count FROM `comments` WHERE comment_date_gmt > DATE_SUB('2018-08-16 18:34:46', INTERVAL 29 DAY) AND comment_approved = 1 GROUP BY comment_post_ID) c ON p.ID = c.comment_post_ID 
WHERE 1 = 1 AND p.post_type IN('post') AND v.view_datetime > DATE_SUB('2018-08-16 18:34:46', INTERVAL 29 DAY) AND p.post_password = '' AND p.post_status = 'publish' GROUP BY v.postid ORDER BY pageviews DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0;
```

[image: JOIN query]

I'm currently trying to rewrite it using subqueries instead of JOINs to check whether performance is better or not.

The following query returns the same results (except for the `comment_count` column as we're only querying two tables instead of three):

```
SELECT p.ID AS id, p.post_title AS title, p.post_author AS uid, v.pageviews AS pageviews 
FROM `posts` p,
    (SELECT SUM(pageviews) AS pageviews, postid FROM `views` WHERE view_datetime > DATE_SUB( '2018-08-16 18:34:46', INTERVAL 29 DAY) GROUP BY postid) v
WHERE 1 = 1 AND p.ID = v.postid AND p.post_type IN('post') AND p.post_password = '' AND p.post_status = 'publish' GROUP BY v.postid ORDER BY pageviews DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0
```

[image: subqueries query]

However, if I add the `comments` table into the mix, posts that don't have comments are being automatically excluded (like ID `2956` with 3100 views), returning a different result when compared to the original query:

```
SELECT p.ID AS id, p.post_title AS title, p.post_author AS uid, v.pageviews AS pageviews, IFNULL(c.comment_count, 0) AS comment_count 
FROM `posts` p,
    (SELECT SUM(pageviews) AS pageviews, postid FROM `views` WHERE view_datetime > DATE_SUB( '2018-08-16 18:34:46', INTERVAL 29 DAY) GROUP BY postid) v,
    (SELECT COUNT(comment_post_ID) AS comment_count, comment_post_ID FROM `comments` WHERE comment_date_gmt > DATE_SUB('2018-08-16 18:34:46', INTERVAL 29 DAY) AND comment_approved = 1 GROUP BY comment_post_ID) c 
WHERE 1 = 1 AND p.ID = v.postid AND v.postid = c.comment_post_ID AND p.post_type IN('post') AND p.post_password = '' AND p.post_status = 'publish' GROUP BY v.postid ORDER BY pageviews DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0
```

[image: subqueries query with comments table]

I'm not really that experienced with this stuff yet (as you can tell) so any help/hints to understand what's going on would be very appreciated.

Comment: Your new queries still have JOINs, but now they are INNER JOINs (that's what `,` means) instead of LEFT JOINs, and given you have no `ON` condition I expect performance will be much worse...

Comment: I also think that'll be the case, Nick, but I want to be 100% sure (hence the reason why I'm rewriting the query). Thanks for the hint on INNER JOINs, I suspected that was the reason why I'm getting these results but I wasn't sure. I'll keep playing around with the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, your new queries still have JOINs. If you want to test performance using subqueries, you need to change the query to something like this (it's my best guess based on your original working query; without seeing table structure and data it's hard to be 100% certain):

```
SELECT id, post_title AS title, post_author AS uid, 
    (SELECT SUM(pageviews) 
     FROM views v 
     WHERE v.postid = posts.id AND 
           v.view_datetime > DATE_SUB('2018-08-16 18:34:46', INTERVAL 29 DAY)
    ) AS pageviews,
    (SELECT COUNT(comment_post_ID) 
     FROM comments c 
     WHERE c.comment_post_ID = posts.id AND
           c.comment_date_gmt > DATE_SUB('2018-08-16 18:34:46', INTERVAL 29 DAY) AND 
           c.comment_approved = 1
    ) AS comment_count
FROM posts
WHERE p.post_type IN('post') AND p.post_password = '' AND p.post_status = 'publish'
ORDER BY pageviews DESC 
LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0;
```

Comment: Just tested your version and it does run faster than my original one (0.02505 seconds vs 0.05449 seconds, 54.03% faster!). I should have included some sample tables but that would have probably made the question bigger than it needed to be (I would have supplied a .sql dump if someone had asked though). Thanks for the help!